# Error installing GMLib 1.5.0

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, gmlib

Delphi 7
Gmlib 1.5.0
Delphi Chromium Embedded: http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/

There is an error while compiling GMLib_D7.bpl:

> [Error] WebControlVCL.pas(519): Expression expected but 'PROCEDURE'
>   found

Code:

```
TChromium(FWebBrowser).Browser.MainFrame.VisitDomProc(
    procedure (const doc: ICefDomDocument)
    begin
      FFields.CommaText := GetFieldsName(doc.GetElementById(FormName));
      Finish := True;
    end
  );
```

Please, help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Delphi 7 didn't support anonymous methods, which is what that code appears to be trying to use.

Comment: Hmmm... GMLib_D7 suggests that this is code for Delphi 7. If they use anonymous methods, they obviously did not properly test this in D7. Or does D7 stand for Delphi XE7?

Comment: There's more to fix there, e.g. the uninitialized value of the `Finish` variable. But this issue is caused by the version dependent definition of the `TCefFastDomVisitorProc` visitor proc for the reason mentioned by @MartynA.

Comment: GMLib, by de moment not support DCEF

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will wait for the best times )

Comment: @cadetill, I would highly suggest using some JavaScript *bridge* for DOM manipulation in CEF. There were versions having the DOM visiting completely broken. Except that it's asynchronous and works with *DOM snapshots*. Better would be implementation of `TCefv8HandlerOwn` handler for firing JavaScript events to Delphi app., and `ICefv8Context.Eval` for synchronous JavaScript function (with return value) calls from Delphi. You don't need to worry about performance, V8 engine is a very fast beast.

Comment: Did you contact the author?

Comment: @David, this is the [author's response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156353/error-installing-gmlib-1-5-0#comment50324846_31156353).